# read string (IP addr) from file not the same as assign manually

Tags: python, string, sockets

I want to read an IP address from an config file and use it in socket for UDP transfer.

```
import configparser
# read config file and create constants
cfgFile = 'OMC-MT.cfg'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()
config.read(cfgFile)
#print(config.sections())
addr = config['addr']
PC_IP = addr['OSC_IP']
PC_PORT = int(addr['OSC_PORT'])
```

In socket.bind

```
PC_RXsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
PC_RXsock.bind((PC_IP, PC_PORT))
```

I'll get this error:

> OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

If I compare the read string and a manually assigned I find no differences:

```
PC_IP2 = '192.168.2.110'
print (len(PC_IP))
print (len(PC_IP2))
```

At least they look the same when print and are at the same length. 
I suppose it has something to do with text encoding but I have no idea how to fix it. 
My text file is saved as utf-8 (Editors says). I use IDLE / Python 3.4.2.
Cheers

Content of OMC-MT.cfg:

```
[addr]
# IP address and port of OSC device e.g. smartphone or tablet 
OSC_IP = 192.168.2.100
OSC_PORT = 54047

# Mastertone IP address
MT_IP=192.168.2.200
MT_PORT=5001

# Computer's IP and UDP ports 
# The RX Port must match with TX port set in OSC software
PC_IP = 192.168.2.110
#PC_IP = 192.168.1.26
PC_PORT = 5005
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the contents of `OMC-MT.cfg`.

Comment: On which device is this code running, the OSC device, the Mastertone, or the Computer?

Comment: you are in the wrong line (OSC_IP). Please check the last IP block of cfg file.

Comment: AAAH I am fine. The problem was this line "PC_IP = addr['OSC_IP']". I assigned the wrong IP and so socket couldn't work with the wrong IP. Thanks for making me read my code again :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider these lines:

```
PC_IP = addr['OSC_IP']
PC_PORT = int(addr['OSC_PORT'])
```

I suppose you actually want:

```
PC_IP = addr['PC_IP']
PC_PORT = int(addr['PC_PORT'])
```